# Why does it keeps echoing the query statement?

Tags: php

I wonder how can I print the title of a certain attribute in my sql database, I wonder why it did output me the query statement instead, I need your help guys. Here below is my php code:

```
<?php
/* getting the last record */
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","task");
$t="SELECT * FROM note ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$thetitle="SELECT title FROM note ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
if(mysqli_query($con, $thetitle)){
mysqli_query($con,$thetitle);
echo ("<button class='call_modal' style='cursor:pointer;'>$thetitle</button>");
}
?>
```

Comment: You're not fetching the result of the query...

Comment: Just fetch the result of the query, you are actually printing it

Comment: okay I'll try $result=mysqli_query($con,$thetitle); ? then print?

Comment: Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps you

```
$query = "SELECT title FROM note ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

// Perform query
// For successful SELECT queries it will return a mysqli_result object
// For other successful queries it will return TRUE. FALSE on failure
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

// Fetch result row as an associative array:
// Note: Fieldnames returned from this function are case-sensitive.
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// Check if any result row was returned
if($row){
    echo '<button class="call_modal" style="cursor:pointer;">'. $row['title'] . '</button>';
}
```

Comment: Maybe explain what you did?

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi i have edited my answer to include comments, hope that improves it

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

```
<?php
    /* getting the last record */
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","task");
    $t = "SELECT * FROM note ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $thetitle = "SELECT title FROM note ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
       if(mysqli_query($con, $thetitle)){

           $result = mysqli_query($con,$thetitle); // run query and store the result in result variable 

           while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ // fetch the result set
                       echo "<button class='call_modal' style='cursor:pointer;'>".$row['title']."</button>";
                 } 


        }
    ?>
```